# How to find the 'centre' of vectors in 3-dimensional space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

How do I find the 'centre' of a set of vectors in $ℝ^3$?

By centre I mean I want to find a vector such that maximum angle between it and any other vector in the set is kept to a minimum. Another way of looking at it would be to find the narrowest cone that contains all the vectors in the set.

I am currently working in MATLAB so methods that are simple to implement in code would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the vectors are contained within some half-space; otherwise any containing cone has to be greater than half-space which makes the geometry rather different.

First, normalize the vectors so that each of them has  length $1$. They form a set $S=\{\vec u_j: j=1,\dots,N\}$ on the unit sphere. You want the smallest spherical cap that contains $S$. This is equivalent to finding a plane $P$ at maximal distance from $0$ that separates $S$ from $0$. Writing the plane  as $P=\{\vec x: \vec x\cdot \vec w= 1\}$, we arrive at the convex minimization problem with linear constraints: 
$$\min \|\vec w\|^2 \quad \text{subject to  } \ \vec u_j\cdot \vec w\ge 1,\quad j=1,\dots,N \tag1$$
The minimizing vector $\vec w$ is unique, and is the center vector that you wanted.

You can do all kinds of convex optimization in Matlab with [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/), and (1) is about the easiest convex optimization problem imaginable. Here it is in [Sage](http://sagemath.org):

```
vectors = [vector([1,2,3]), vector([1,0,2]), vector([3,2,4]), vector([5,2,-1]), vector([1,1,-1])] 
unit_vectors = [v/v.norm() for v in vectors]
constraints = [lambda x,vec=u: vector(x).dot_product(vec)-1 for u in unit_vectors]
target = lambda x: vector(x).norm()
minimize_constrained(target,constraints,[3,3,3])
```

Output: `(1.38121931125,0.778255829438,0.427424333123)`, which looks reasonable.

Sage requires an initial point of optimization, which can be any vector that meets the constraints: you'll have it when you know a half-space containing your vectors.

---

I spent an inordinate amount of time pondering why the earlier version of this code didn't work, until I tried StackOverflow: [Evaluating a list of python lambda functions only evaluates the last list element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6059205).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does exactly what I wanted. It took me a while to get my head round what it's doing, but now I really like this solution and it has helped deepen my understanding so thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply compute the mean of the vectors. Imagine a point cloud in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where each point is the end point of a vector starting at the origin. The mean vector is then a vector/point in the "middle" of this point cloud. In Matlab this is especially simple. Define a matrix $A$ with the vectors in its rows. If $N$ is the number of vectors, then
$$\tt{m=sum(A)/N}$$
is the mean vector.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately my point cloud is denser on one side than the other so the mean is skewed to one side.